# how to concatenate after list. Append for each item

Tags: python, json, dataframe, concatenation, export-to-csv

suppose I have a,b,c (each is index values, subject values and text values)
I created list and then created list with append each of them

the output should be

| id | subject | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | subject1 | text1 |
| 2 | subject2 | text2 |

and so on and I want it to extract it like that also to CSV in columns.

now I have them only in one column in CSV

| column |
| --- |
| 1 |
| subject1 |
| text1 |
| 2 |
| subject2 |
| text2 |

How can I extract them to columns instead of rows?

```
data = []
#df = pd.DataFrame()
for row in res:
            result=( ''.join(row[0]))
            p = Payload(result)
            data.append(p.a)
            data.append(p.b)
            data.append(p.c)
          
            #data_new=print(a+b+c)
            #data_new =(''.join(data))
            data_new=np.concatenate([data])
            
            
#col = pd.DataFrame(data)  
                
df = pd.DataFrame(data_new)
print(df)

#df.values.reshape(100, 1)

#print(df)

  
df.to_csv('test.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', index=False)             
            #df.loc[len(df.ind
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample of input datataframe and expected output?

Comment: is it clearer now? please let me know what alse to add

Comment: With input do you mean *output*? Now you have dataframe with one `"column"`?

Comment: yes. I need 3 columns, and now I just have one long column

Comment: I've added an example how you could create a dataframe with 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, to have three columns add to list `data` dictionaries with three keys:

```py
data = []
for row in res:
    p = Payload("".join(row[0]))
    data.append({"id": p.a, "subject": p.b, "text": p.c})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv("test.csv", sep="\t", encoding="utf-8", index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks now it's better but I still see the first header like that:"idsubjecttext"

Comment: @d12 Maybe change the `sep="\t"` to `sep=","` (also, when you load the file to excel set correct separator)?

Comment: Thank you it worked and you're a genius!